# Pentaho: Cannot import XML data from a URL

Tags: curl, xml-parsing, ssl-certificate, rest-client, pentaho-data-integration

Question:
Using Pentaho, I need to download XML data from a URL. To access this URL, I need to validate a certificate (.pfx file) and then download the data. The URL has certain parameters like username, password, activestatus, and type.

I have used below tasks as an input in a ktr:

1. Generate Rows - this has my URL as an input string (full all parameters)
2. Rest Client - I have added input as below:
   General tab: a. Accept URL from the field (check marked)
   b. URL field name (Generate Rows)
   c. HTTP method - POST
   d. Application Type - XML
   e. Result field name - result
   SSL tab: Trust store file: Imported .pfx file from my local drive
   Trust store password: provided password for the .pfx file
3. Write to log: selected "result" from above step.

When I run this workflow/transformation, I get below error:

Your client is not allowed to access the requested object.

However, when I type the URL on Edge/Chrome, it works fine. Also, I tried another tool called Postman, and received the output.

Need assistance as why it is not being executed in Pentaho.

Pentaho version: 9.3.0.0-428 (April 2022)

I have used below tasks as an input in a ktr:

1. Generate Rows - this has my URL as an input string (full all parameters)
2. Rest Client - I have added input as below:
   General tab: a. Accept URL from the field (check marked)
   b. URL field name (Generate Rows)
   c. HTTP method - POST
   d. Application Type - XML
   e. Result field name - result
   SSL tab: Trust store file: Imported .pfx file from my local drive
   Trust store password: provided password for the .pfx file
3. Write to log: selected "result" from above step.

My expectation was that the XML data is populated through these Pentaho tasks when the Rest Client task is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it not complex as you think.

Here is my example, I craw exchange rate data from website of bank.

Before you start, let sure that you have internet, right url.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried this scenario. However, Http client does not have an option to select/store/import SSL certificate that I use to authenticate the website. In my development, I've used REST Client task and as listed above (in my question) have listed all parameters in all the tabs within that.